# iron:router check if route loaded with history.back

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I try to detect how the user got to the route. There are 3 cases I guess:

1. The page was loaded directly by the URL
2. The page was loaded by clicking on a Link
3. The page was loaded by clicking on the history back or forward buttons in the browser

Is there any way to detect the 3 cases or - which would be enough for me - to detect if the user came to the route by the 2nd case ?

**Why ?**
In my project I have a List-Layout. When I am scrolling down and clicking on a Link in this List the new Template will be rendered but the window has now a scrollTop Value because of the scrolling in the list.

I fixed this with this:

```
Router.configure({
  onAfterAction : function () {
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
  }
});
```

With this fix after every page load the page will be scrolled to the top (like its normal).

**But:**

When I clicked on a link in the list and then I click on the "Back" button in my Browser (history.back) the page will also be scrolled to the top (because of my fix) - without the fix the page will be automatically jump to the last position.

Because of this I need something like this:

```
Router.configure({
  onAfterAction : function () {
    var historyBack;
    historyBack = CheckIfHistoryBackWasClicked();
    if (!historyBack) jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
  }
});
```

Anyone any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `click` event handler to your links and set a `scrollToTop` session variable there:

```
"click a": function(e) {
    Session.set("scrollToTop", true);
    return true;
}
```

Then, do something like this:

```
Router.configure({
  onAfterAction : function () {
    if (Session.get("scrollToTop") == true) {
      jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
      Session.set("scrollToTop", false);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is possible of course but to work with sessions I find in this case wrong. Is there no javascript solution ? :/

Comment: I don't know if you come from a background where "session" means that you'll use server memory to hold information, but in this case it just means you're creating a reactive variable. A Meteor session variable stays only in the client and isn't shared between tabs. You'll eventually learn that this is the best solution for a lot of things in Meteor.

Comment: Further reading: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session and https://www.meteor.com/try/8

Comment: Thats right - I know the meteor Sessions and this is very useful - but I try to prevent using Sessions if its possible. To put everything in Sessions is the wrong way I thing.